# Сортировка меток по иконкам

Tags: сортировка

Помогите плизз..

У меня есть большая карта клиентов, все со своими иконками, например:

- Желтый дом - наша розница
- Синий дом - Наши оптовики
- Красный череп - Закупают у конкурента 1
- Зеленый череп - Закупают у конкурента 2 и т.д.

Есть ли возможность отсортировать их штатными средствами, например по "Красный череп - Закупают у конкурента 1"?

Или может создавать метки надо по другому, для возможности сортировки?

Если нет вариантов, подскажите куда копать по API, если можно с примером, а то в этом очень мало познаний...

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Штатными средствами чего? Что значит "отсортировать по красный череп"? Может вам нужно отфильтровать?

Comment: Да, отфильтровать наверное)))

Comment: Ну например, чтоб на карте показать менеджерам, всех клиентов, которые закупаются у "конкурента 1"

Comment: Теперь осталось нам угадать, где вы эти иконки выводите

Comment: https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/